# How to optimize query analysis and storage costs in Bigquery export data streaming inserts that occur at varied intervals during the day?

Tags: database, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

I am exploring options to optimize query analysis and cost to store data in a BigQuery table. If we are able to reuse the query that is made on a larger data vs reuse/extract data from the last queried result to only save cost for running the entire query again.

Limitations

- Cannot use cached results since the data is streaming inserts and every rewrite will invalidate the cached results.

Even if there is a programmatic solution that can be built, trying to validate if data inconsistencies happens or managing it whenever a data is out of sync.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

To analyze BigQuery SQL cost usage you can list all BigQuery jobs (BigQuery API) and analyze bytes/slots usage and the execution time. Besides caching, you can analyze queries to see if there is any candidate for  [Partitioning and Clustering](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/clustered-tables) that could reduce significant cost and execution time. Reading other BigQuery SO posts I am under impression that Materialized Views are around the corner, that would be another great performance and cost optimization.

To optimize cost itself you can compare on-demand or [slot reservation](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reservations-intro) pricing model.

To optimize streaming insert cost, as long you can accept 2 min delay (as opposed sec delay with streaming) you can take into account event-driven serverless data ingestion like [BqTail](https://github.com/viant/bqtail)

When it comes to caching you may also explore eager caching options which creates cache for most commonly used SQL every time underlying data changes, but in that case you have to control all data ingestion to recreate cache. (*possible with BqTail  API post load task)

Comment: Thanks @Adrian. Your thoughts are helpful, I am currently evaluating Clustering Tables and would it even cost the same or significantly lower the cost.